# NodeJS + Socket.IO + Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io in order to send message to the user when he join my site and initializing his details using cookie sent by the client. After a while and few refreshes performed my queries stop working.

Here's my code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
var user = false;
socket.on('hash', function(hash, gameType) {
    socket.join(gameType);
    query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `hash` = ' + pool.escape(hash), function(err, row) {
        if((err) || (!row.length)) return socket.disconnect();
        user = row[0];
        users[user.steamid] = {
            socket: socket.id,
            balance: parseInt(row[0].balance)
        }
        socket.emit('message', {
            balance: row[0].balance,
            type: 'hello',
            user: row[0].steamid
        });
    }
}

function query(sql, callback) {
console.log(callback);
if (typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    callback = function() {};
}
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        logger.info('DB Connection ID: '+connection.threadId);
        connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
            if(err) return callback(err);
            connection.release();
            return callback(null, rows);
        });
    });
}

log4js.configure({
appenders: [
    { type: 'console' },
    { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/site.log' }
]
});
var logger = log4js.getLogger();

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    database: 'test',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'pw'
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
   logger.trace('Strange error');
   logger.debug(err);
});
```

Comment: I've edited the code check it out!

Comment: Looks better. You should actually log your error messages instead of just disconnecting the sockets, and it doesn't look like `process.on('uncaughtException', ...)` will ever be invoked since you don't `throw` anything anywhere.

Comment: The problem is that when there are a lot of connections my queries stop executing and the socket is not sending messages to the clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is the reason is you exhaust the connection pool.

```
if(err) return callback(err); << after some erros here
connection.release(); << not released if there is an error
```

just release the connection before this line